# How do I produce a column of numeric range of vectors in R?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, seq, data-wrangling

How do I apply a function like seq() to two columns denoting a range of values.

```
  start <- c(1,5,10,14,23)
  end <- c(4,9,13,22,28)
  df <- cbind(start, end) 
  df %<>% as.data.frame()
```

I tried using mutate function to apply seq, but to no avail. I realized the mutate function can't apply individual column values.

```
  df  %>% mutate(range = seq(start, end))
```

Any indications appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using the `purrr` package is

```
purrr::map2(df$start, df$end, seq)
```

with output

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
[1] 10 11 12 13

[[4]]
[1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22

[[5]]
[1] 23 24 25 26 27 28
```

Note that the sequences have different lengths due to the different start and end values. Hence, they are in a list instead of `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `seq` function rowwise -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(range = list(seq(start, end))) %>%
  ungroup -> res

res

#  start   end range    
#  <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
#1     1     4 <int [4]>
#2     5     9 <int [5]>
#3    10    13 <int [4]>
#4    14    22 <int [9]>
#5    23    28 <int [6]>
```

where the `range` column has list of values.

```
res$range

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 5 6 7 8 9

#[[3]]
#[1] 10 11 12 13

#[[4]]
#[1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22

#[[5]]
#[1] 23 24 25 26 27 28
```